# Is it possible to swap lifetime sales in lieu of time in Survival analysis?

Tags: survival

My question is, is it possible to swap other values in lieu of time in survival analysis? Particularly for Kaplan-Meir.

If I swap total sales in lieu of time, would this essentially mean at the 50th percentile, the total sales generated is \$X after accounting for censoring. Or where i have strata, at the 50th percentile of strata group A is \$X and group B is \$Y

Comment: I am aware of something similar for bond defaults. see bond vintage curve analysis. eg https://www.listendata.com/2019/09/credit-risk-vintage-analysis.html.  You would have to explain your lifetime sales... is there a maximum lifetime sale? is it infinite (unending)?

Comment: Thanks. Incidentally, I'm aware of the vintage curve in the credit risk world. From my understanding, max lifetime sale will only apply when status = 'dead' in survival analysis world. And where they are still alive, and censoring is applied the % in Y-axis should be reflected accordingly.

Comment: I was asking if there was a limit (if they don't leave). So since there is an infinite payoff, you need to use discounting to get a finite discounted payoff and then your vintage curve can be proportions of the discounted payoff..